# specification cpu and gpu for opencl

Tags: opencl, gpu, cpu, difference

any one help i execute opencl kernel program for image processing and want to know the process faster when the kerenl execute on cpu or gpu
i using tool "GPU caps viewer" take picture for specification cpu and gpu and want to know the best for run opencl kernel code to  the cpu or gpu . why??

the gpu info

[image: AMD GPU]

and for cpu 
amd info

[image: AMD CPU]

intel

[image: Intel CPU]

and i want to know why three option different for cpu (intel , amd) info

```
  constant buffer    amd 64KB   intel 128KB
  max sampler        amd 16     intel 480
  opencl extention   amd 16     intel 14
  work group size    amd 16     intel 14
```

any help

thanks

Comment: time the kernel running on each device. then you will know which one is faster.

Comment: how can compute it any example .

Comment: from device information what is the best cpu or gpu ???? can you know that ??

Comment: You can't know how fast it is, is impossible. The cores, the memory size or the work size are non-related to the speed. The only option is to measure. IE: Can you say that a P4 3GHz is faster than a i3? By looking at the clock speed? Or the cores? Simply not.

Comment: i want to know why cpu faster than gpu for opencl edge detection for video process 
for cpu process  number frame per seconds greater than gpu for the same program and kernel but my gpu is good i play battlefield 3 ??? i want to know why ???

Comment: soory for my bad english , the tool gpu caps viewer have example when run opencl on gpu process faster than cpu

Comment: i ask question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23141994/opencl-kernel-for-real-time-image-processing?noredirect=1#comment35394355_23141994
 but not found any answer i want to know if any core in gpu not work idle ????